# Why there is showing only one document in firebase firestore when extracting on flutter app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my firebase firestore, there are two documents in the January 2022 collection. [image]

[image]
**But when I iterate over January 2022, in my flutter app, it's showing only one documents. WHY?**
[image]

Comment: Add some fields to `Logs` collection and try again

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content, going forward. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Ok Frank I will take care of it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `Logs` **document** in your database. The Firebase console merely shows that title, so that it can show the documents in the `Sunday, January 9` collection under it. The console shows `Logs` in italic font to make this distinction clear.

Since there is no `Logs` document, it won't returned by your read of the `January 2022` collection. You will either have to specify `Logs` in your code (since you already *know* that logs may exist when you write the application code), or you'll have to create a document (even without any fields, or just a single field).